# Using key-value programming (KVP) with Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C with Cocoa a lot of tasks can be accomplished without explicit loops by using Key-Value Programming (KVP). For example, I can find the largest number in an array with a single line of code:

```
NSNumber * max = [numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
```

How can I do the same thing with swift? Arrays do not appear to support valueForKeyPath method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The array will actually respond to valueForKeyPath function - you just need to cast the array to `AnyObject` so that the compiler doesn't complain. As follows:

```
var max = (numbers as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@max.self") as Double
```

or even, for a union of objects:

```
(labels as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@unionOfObjects.text")
```

If `labels` above is a collection of labels, the above will return an array of all the strings of the `text` property of each label.

It is also equivalent to the following:

```
(labels as AnyObject).valueForKey("text")
```

... just as it is in Objective-C :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the reduce function of Array

```
let numbers = [505,4,33,12,506,21,1,0,88]
let biggest = numbers.reduce(Int.min,{max($0, $1)})
println(biggest) // prints 506
```

Good explanation [here](http://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use (at least) the `didSet` `willSet` provided by Swift on properties. I guess it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about KVP, but KVO isn't currently supported in Swift. See also this dev forums thread:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/227909