# How to use a Key Value Observer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

For my purpose I have AVFoundation set up to take photos and I want to make sure the exposure and whitebalance(adjustingExposure, adjustingWhiteBalance) are finished adjusting before it saves the imagedata . Otherwise it comes out dark for the first photo.

How can I set up a key value observer to run code after the values are changed? And how/where is the best place to initiate it?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24039941/335858) has a link to dev forums at apple, which supposedly say that KVO isn't available (or isn't available yet). I no longer have access to dev forums, but if you do, the link could be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get the image make a `var` with a `didSet` and that var save the imaged
ex

```
var image : UIImage{//or what type your image is,Maby NSData,but I'm not sure
didSet{
   // adjustingExposure and adjustingWhiteBalance
 }
```

and then you save it EX:

```
func grabImage(){//is an example IDK your code,I say that this func captured the imagedate
image = imageThatYouTook
//then save the image data from the image var
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't really KVO. The `didSet` method is part of Swift's observable properties feature, and it's a fine alternative to KVO, but it is a different mechanism. See http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/11/swift-kvo-alternatives.html for more info.